# I'm getting an error displaying the user's profile photo on laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-6

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = Admin::when($request->keyword, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('nama_lengkap', 'like', "%{$request->keyword}%");
    })->paginate(5);

    $data->appends($request->only('keyword'));

    return view('admin.crud_admin.index', compact('data'));
}
```

**Model Admin.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'avatar', 'nama_lengkap', 'email', 'password',
];

public function getAvatar()
{
    if (!$this->avatar) {
        return asset('images/default.png');
    }

    return asset('images/' . $this->avatar);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-user-link" id="dropdown-user" href="javascript:void(0);"
   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="user-nav d-sm-flex d-none">
        <span class="user-name font-weight-bolder">{{ Auth::user()->nama_lengkap }}</span>
        <span class="user-status">Admin</span>
    </div>
    <span class="avatar"
        ><img class="round" src="{{ $data->getAvatar('avatar') }}"
          alt="avatar" height="40" width="40"
        /><span class="avatar-status-online"></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

this does not appear even there is an error:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getAvatar does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Helpdesk\resources\views\admin\crud_admin\index.blade.php)"

Can you help me? please this is important to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `$data` is a Collection, since you assign to it this:

```
$data = ...->paginate(5);
```

Thus, you have to loop over it:

```
@foreach($data as $user)
   ...
   {{ $user->getAvatar('avatar') }}
   ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you Berto99 this is working well :)

Comment: @Putra you're welcome, feel free to mark the answer as correct

Comment: but this makes the user's profile photo repeat, until the last data?

Comment: @Putra in $data you have 5 admins as you can see in the controller, this will print the 5 profile pictures of those admins